# Extending User and UserCreationForm

Tags: python, django

I need your help.
I extending class User and add same field, than extending UserCreationForm, but form is not valid.
Code crash in if form.is_valid().
Please help, why my form is not correctly?

## models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile')
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

My register form

## forms.py

```
class MyRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
print "OK!"
nick_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True, widget=forms.TextInput)
print "Ook"
class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
def save(self, commit=True):
    if not commit:
        raise NotImplementedError("Can't create User and UserProfile without database save")
    print "Saving..."
    user = super(MyRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.nick_name = self.cleaned_data["nick_name"]
    user_profile = UserProfile(user=user, nick_name=self.cleaned_data['nick_name'])
    user_profile.save()
    print "Saving complete"
    return user, user_profile
```

Register function

## views.py

```
def reg(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = MyRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            print username
            password1 = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            print password1
            password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
            print password2
            nick_name = form.cleaned_data['nick_name']
            print nick_name
            form.clean_username()
            if password1 == password2:
                new_user = form.save()
                return render_to_response('registration/registration_complete.html')
            else:
                print "Password error"
                return render_to_response('registration/registration_fail.html')
        else:
            print "FORM error" #ТУТ ВАЛИТСЯ :(
            return render_to_response('registration/registration_fail.html')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm() # An unbound form
    return render_to_response('registration/registration_new_user.html', {
        'form': form,
        },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In setting

## settings.py

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'registration.UserProfile'
```

Registration template

## registration_new_user.html

```
    {% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Registration</h1>
  <form action="registration" method="post">
    {% if form.error_dict %}
      <p class="error">Please fix the error.</p>
    {% endif %}
    {% if form.username.errors %}
      {{ form.username.html_error_list }}
    {% endif %}
    <label for="id_username">Login:</label><br> {{ form.username }}<br>
    {% if form.password1.errors %}
      {{ form.password1.html_error_list }}
    {% endif %}
    <label for="id_password1">pass:</label><br> {{ form.password1 }}<br>
    {% if form.password2.errors %}
      {{ form.password2.html_error_list }}
    {% endif %}
    <label for="id_password2">pass(again):</label><br> {{ form.password2 }}<br>
    {% if form.nick_name.errors %}
      {{ form.nick_name.html_error_list }}
    {% endif %}
    <label for="id_nick_name">nick:</label><br> {{ form.nick_name }}<br>
      <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Reg" />
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the indentation just a miss or...?

Comment: @lov3catch: In python indentation is part of the syntax. Likewise, please indent your code in the question so that everyone knows what is your code.

Comment: What error are the form returning?

Comment: @PauloBu: any error in console & any error in browser.
Just print: FORM error

Comment: Yes but, is it an exception, are there normal forms errors for fields missing? If so, can you post what happens when you submit? That will lead us a little :)

Comment: @J.C.Leitão: With indentation everything okay.

Comment: @PauloBu: just redirect to registration/registration_fail.html
Take redirect command in this place (def reg() in views.py):
else:
        print "FORM error"
        return render_to_response('registration/registration_fail.html')

Comment: Ok, I can see is a validation point, what I'm trying to suggest you is that try to figure out **what the errors are**. There are several path that may lead to `registration_fail`, figure out which one is: is it `password!=password2? or !form.is_valid()`. Instead of print `FORM Error` try to print the form.errors dict so it may bring some light.

Comment: @PauloBu: error in form.is_valid().

Comment: Yes but what? Which form field is giving the error?

Comment: @PauloBu: How can I check it?

Comment: You may print the form.errors dictionary. Normally it comes this way: `{field:error_string,...}` so you will know which field is giving which error and tell us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @PauloBu: at first sight my class MyRegisterForm is correct?

Comment: With the proper indentation yes, it seems correct. Dude, is not that hard to read the form.errors dict and that would bring a lot of light. For instance you can do: after `form.is_valid()`, in the `else`: `raise Exception(form.errors)`

Comment: @PauloBu: I have error:
<li>user<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.
But, I don`t have field like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have several issues in your code. For instance, you override `UserCreationForm` with `MyRegistrationForm` and indeed you instantiate the latter when the request is a `POST`, but when is not, you pass the template a normal `UserCreationForm`.

You do have a `user` in your `UserCreationForm` because this is a `ModelForm` whose model is `UserProfile` and there you have defined a `user` field. So it makes perfect sense that the forms complaint about this when you create it with the `POST`.

I don't see a very clear solution here because your code is somewhat tricky but first of all, use the same form with both `GET` and `POST` request type so this line in your views

```
form = UserCreationForm() # An unbound form
```

Would change for this one:

```
form = MyRegistrationForm() # An unbound form
```

In the template it won't appear the field `user` because you don't include them but it is in the form. As you are creating a new user, that field should be set to non-required because no user will be associated with the `UserProfile` because you are creating the user. You can set it to non-required adding the parameter `blank=True` to the model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, related_name='profile', blank=True)
    nick_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

**UPDATE:**

This is the code for your base class `UserCreationForm` `save` method:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

As you can see, this code assumes that the user has a `set_password` attribute, in order to fix this, you have to add a `def set_password(self, raw_password)` method to your `UserProfile` class. This error happens because the form base class is designed to be used with normal Django `User` class, any other error you may encounter like this you will probably solve it by adding the fields required to your `UserProfile`. This one solves like this:

```
class UserProfile:
    ...
    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        # whatever logic you need to set the password for your user or maybe
        self.user.set_password(raw_password)
    ...
```

I hope this bring some light to the problem. Good luck!

Comment: thx you! You are awesome. form = MyRegistrationForm() # An unbound form this code fix my template, and now I see fields for input nick-name. But registration is not work.
Traceback: 'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'set_password'

Comment: Code was stopped in this line:
user_profile = super(MyRegisterForm, self).save(commit=False)

Comment: I confused and go to created mini-project with only registration for understanding how it works. Thx you verymuch.